# Altered interpretation from Russian to English

Tags: python, replace, str-replace, transliteration

I need to create a program that would transliterate in different ways Russian names into English.

For example, Russian last name:

> Муравьёв

Possible interpretation in English:

> Muravyov; Myravyev; Muraviev; Muraviov; Murav'ev; Muravev; Murav'yev; Murav'ov; Muravjov; Muravjev; Mouravieff; Muravieff; Mouravief;
>   Muravief; Muraviof; Muravioff;

I found existing transliteration Python package [transliterate_1.9](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate), it has a standardized form of transliteration from Cyrilic to English.
The problem is that I need also another possible interpretation to English. I thought about replacing method in Python but didn't figure it out how to make a right code.

By this time I have this:

```
def translit(string):

capital_letters = {
    u'А': u'A',
    u'Б': u'B',
    u'В': u'V',
    u'Г': u'G',
    u'Д': u'D',
    u'Е': u'E',
    u'Ё': u'E',
    u'Ж': u'Zh',
    u'З': u'Z',
    u'И': u'I',
    u'Й': u'Y',
    u'К': u'K',
    u'Л': u'L',
    u'М': u'M',
    u'Н': u'N',
    u'О': u'O',
    u'П': u'P',
    u'Р': u'R',
    u'С': u'S',
    u'Т': u'T',
    u'У': u'U',
    u'Ф': u'F',
    u'Х': u'H',
    u'Ц': u'Ts',
    u'Ч': u'Ch',
    u'Ш': u'Sh',
    u'Щ': u'Sch',
    u'Ъ': u'',
    u'Ы': u'Y',
    u'Ь': u'',
    u'Э': u'E',
    u'Ю': u'Yu',
    u'Я': u'Ya'
}

lower_case_letters = {
    u'а': u'a',
    u'б': u'b',
    u'в': u'v',
    u'г': u'g',
    u'д': u'd',
    u'е': u'e',
    u'ё': u'e',
    u'ж': u'zh',
    u'з': u'z',
    u'и': u'i',
    u'й': u'y',
    u'к': u'k',
    u'л': u'l',
    u'м': u'm',
    u'н': u'n',
    u'о': u'o',
    u'п': u'p',
    u'р': u'r',
    u'с': u's',
    u'т': u't',
    u'у': u'u',
    u'ф': u'f',
    u'х': u'h',
    u'ц': u'ts',
    u'ч': u'ch',
    u'ш': u'sh',
    u'щ': u'sch',
    u'ъ': u'',
    u'ы': u'y',
    u'ь': u'',
    u'э': u'e',
    u'ю': u'yu',
    u'я': u'ya'
}

translit_string = ""

for index, char in enumerate(string):
    if char in lower_case_letters.keys():
        char = lower_case_letters[char]
    elif char in capital_letters.keys():
        char = capital_letters[char]
        if len(string) > index+1:
            if string[index+1] not in lower_case_letters.keys():
                char = char.upper()
        else:
            char = char.upper()
    translit_string += char

return translit_string
```

I'm a new coder and programming in about 2-3 month and learned a litle bit of Python. Could I use `or` in strings to get other possible answers? Or maybe how to use here a `replacing method` to get also other possible answers.

Comment: You should update your question with the results you get versus the results you expect.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Obviously from your example, one Cyrillic letter can be transliterated to MULTIPLE Latin replacements. The replacements can have more than 1 character.  E.g. Cyrillic lower case y can be replaced by latin `y`, `u`, or `ou`. You need one big dict mapping single Cyrillic characters to a list or tuple of replacements ... one entry would be `"y": ['u', 'y', 'ou']. I don't see the point of having 2 dicts, one for capital letters and one for small letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could fork the [CyrTranslit](https://github.com/opendatakosovo/cyrillic-transliteration) Python package and follow the [instructions on how to add support for a new language](https://github.com/opendatakosovo/cyrillic-transliteration/blob/master/README.md#how-can-i-contribute) to include alternative Russian transliterations dictionaries.